# What text to display for a waiting screen in a game?

Tags: games

I am making a game that requires more than one person and I'm not sure what I should tell users while they wait. Here are some ideas I've come up with.

- Waiting for players
- Not enough players (2 minimum)
- 2 or more players needed

I'm not sure which is best to use or if there is a better solution all together.

Comment: I know this is outside of what you're asking but you shouldn't make players "wait."  Any "wait" is part of your game - it could even be the first thing a player does.  Players shouldn't be able to start a game until it's playable.  If your game requires more than one player, create an interface (can be external) that lets players click to enter into a queue and notify them when an opponent is ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using "Waiting for other players" would work just fine. You can tell the users before they attempt to start the game that it will require more than one player (i.e. The button could say something like "Match me to another player")

One thing to also consider is adding in a timeout feature. For example, if a user isn't matched with an opponent within a certain time frame, they will be asked to try again.

Answer (score 0):

If you could tell us what kind of game is that or the genre, would help us figure out a better tone of language to the user while they wait.